# Remove one song from iTunes account

Tags: itunes

Can I remove one song from my iTunes account so that it doesn't appear on my iPhone without disabling Show All?

Muse made their upcoming album *Drones* available for preorder at the same time that they made one of its tracks, *Psycho*, available for purchase so, instantly, I bought *Psycho* from iTunes and, later on, preordered the Deluxe Edition of *Drones* from muse.mu. I then found out that the Deluxe Edition of *Drones* comes with digital downloads of any singles that have been or will be released which I initially ignored as I already owned *Psycho* but I later realised that the MP3 file had a much higher bitrate than the iTunes file. So, I deleted the iTunes file but, when I play *Drones* on repeat. *Psycho* plays twice because iTunes is streaming the track attached to my account and then playing the local, as you can see here:

[image]

Comment: So what is holding you back?

Comment: I don't know how to remove a purchase from my iTunes account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song you bought from iTunes Store is not yet downloaded into your iPhone, but will be streamed from iTunes while playing.

There is no option to cancel the purchase and remove the song - from your iPhone. But you can do that from iTunes, from your PC or Mac. **Please refer to [this](http://www.imore.com/how-request-refund-itunes-or-app-store-purchase) to find more about how this request can be made**.

1. Launch iTunes on your PC or Mac.
2. Click on your name at the top and select Account Info.
3. Enter password when prompted.
4. Click on See All under Purchase History.
5. Click on the arrow next to the group that contains the
   purchase you'd like a refund for.
6. Click on Report a Problem next to the single purchase you'd like a
   refund for, unless there is only one, then you may use the large
   Report a Problem button.
7. You will be routed to Apple's website.
8. Follow the steps after signing in and request the Refund option and
   explain why.

Comment: I've reported a problem with the purchase and they say they will get back to me within 48 hours so I'll keep everyone posted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: On 2015/04/03, Rachel, iTunes Store/Mac App Store Advisor, submitted a refund for the song to me.

On 2015/04/07, I received the refund and the song disappeared from my Purchased history on the desktop iTunes client but not my iPhone despite disabling "Show All Music" and force-quitting the Music app.

On 2015/04/08, as advised, I removed all music from my iPhone but the song remained along with a handful of other iTunes-purchased content.

On 2015/04/11, the song disappeared for unknown reasons and Rachel granted my iTunes account 5 free song credits "in appreciation for your patience". :)